# How would I report a user for the content of bio?

Tags: support, abuse

Since I believe we are not supposed to link directly to a specific user in questions here, how should I report a users bio for moderator attention?

For Questions/Answers/Comments there are obvious flagging links, but not for a profile.

The user in question doesn't have any active questions at the moment (the one they had has already been closed and deleted) that could be used as anchor.

Comment: Well, no links to that profile at all so extremely low odds that anybody would see it.  How did you?  You can still flag a deleted post.

Comment: I was following up to see if they have reposted the question to a more on topic site (they had not taken the suggestion that the original question was off-topic well)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the user doesn't have any posts, just flag one of **your** posts for moderator attention and include the relevant details and links there.

But you say that the user **does** have a post, only that is currently closed and deleted. **You can still raise custom mod flag in a deleted post**, and since you are over 10k you can see the post if you know the URL.

(You may flag any other post, but it would be awkward to flag an unrelated post. The important bit is that the custom message is informative enough for the mod to act upon; and if possible put the important bits at the very beggining of the message, so the mod doesn't review your flag too fast).